# Doing tests with objects of different length

Tags: r, shapefile

I am trying to calculate the moran I index (for spatial autocorrelation) using the the following argument:

```
moran.test(data_total$prod_ser, dnb60.listw, randomisation=F)
```

The error I get is that the two objects are of different length.

Vector `prod_ser` belonging to data.frame `data_total` (first object in () ) is 2373 long (in other words `data_total` contain 2373 observations-firms). I am trying to see whether this variable is spatially auto-correlated.

`dnb50.listw` is a `nb2listw` object, spatial weights created based on distance between coordinates of the country's regions.Its length is 3. This object is created using a polygon shapefile, containing 25 regions.This polygon shapefile contains regions's ID, which `data_total` data.frame contains too (along with the regions' coordinates).

I tried to extend the length of `dnb60.listw` object to 2373 (the length of `prod_ser` vector), but that would not be possible since it is a `nb2listw` object.

I also tried creating list object using data_total (since this data_frame does have coordinates and region's ID). However,I would get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("coords") :
>     no applicable method for 'coords' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Is there any idea of how to make these two objects (`prod_ser` and `dnb60.listw`) of the same length so that I can do the testing?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Provide sample input data and specify which package the `moran.test` function comes from.

Comment: @MrFlick I gave the reproducible example on the following post stackoverflow.com/questions/31101043/… If you have any idea how to sort this out-it would be great!